# iOS view stuck at 320 by 480

Tags: ios8, xcode6, autolayout

I am using xcode 6 targeting ios8. I have a single page application, where I removed the storyboard to get it to an xcode 5 empty application template. I then created a new storyboard and added a tableview. When I run it on a device or emulator the windows is restricted at 320x480 and centered vertically on the screen. This leaves black bars above and below the table view.

My appdelegate looks like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    MyTableViewController *mtvc = (MyTableViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    mtvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

I have tried turning autolayout & size classes off. Cleaned the project.

Screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/09tu1ihdpomezum/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-18%20at%209.09.59%20AM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS decides the supported screen sizes based on the launch images that the app bundle has. If you don't have any, it'll only support the 3,5" displays sizes. Enable the support for bigger displays by adding the launch images for those. The sizes for the images are listed in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2).

On iOS 8, you can also use `launch screen file` instead of traditional launch images. Launch screen file is a xib or storyboard that will be shown when the app is launched. It's possible to support all the displays sizes by using single file. The usage of launch screen file is explained, for instance, [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/12/24/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html) or by [Ole Begemann here](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the launch screen file issue. That did it!